# Sort by two class variables in proc summary including all missing combination of classes

Tags: sas

The raw data

```
GrantNumber    ServiceID   Region1   Total

    1             1          1        50
    1             2          1        60
    2             1          2        70
```

I need my output to include missing combination of class variables. Then I want my output to be sorted based on these two class variables ServiceID and Region1 
Example
ServiceID , Region1 and Total are columns headers

```
ServiceID Region1      Total

1         Atlantic     50
2         Atlantic     40
3         Atlantic     30
1         West         20
2         West         10
3         West         .
4         West         .
```

I have tried to include completetypes to interact with preloadfmt and sort it by one class variable it does not work.

```
 Proc summary data=Allocate.Merge_All_s1 nway completetypes ;
 By ServiceID;
 Types ServiceID*Region1;
 Class Region1 ServiceID / preloadfmt missing ;
 Var  Total
 output out=Allocate.Merge_All_s_Aggregate  sum=/keepLen;
 run;

 Data Allocate.Merge_All_final;
 set Allocate.Merge_All_s_Aggregate(Keep=ServiceID Region1 Total);
 run;

 ODS HTML File= "\Results12.XLS";
 Proc Print Data=Allocate.Merge_All_final ;
 Run;
 ODS HTML Close;
```

Comment: So by missing you don't mean missing values in the data, but values that are in your list of possible values but just don't happen to appear in this sample of data?

Comment: Why are you using both BY and CLASS?  Why not just add SERVICEID to the CLASS statement instead of using a BY statement?

Comment: Please include sample data that illustrates how your raw data is structured and the expected output - I believe that's the first table but I edited your post to make it legible. Please make sure your questions are formatted correctly, it helps you get a faster answer.

Comment: I have included the an example of the raw data @Reeza

Comment: by missing I mean combination of classes that have no values the last two rows of the  example output @Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want the `CLASSDATA` option. That let's you give it a dataset with all of the possible combinations.

So create a dataset with all of the combinations.

```
data classdata;
  if 0 then set have(keep=ServiceId region);
  do ServiceId =1 to 4;
    do Region1 = 1 to 2;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Another easy way to make the CLASSDATA is to use full join in PROC SQL from individual lists.

```
proc sql;
  create table classdata as select * 
  from (select distinct serviceid from master_list_of_service_ids)
     , (select distinct region1 from master_list_of_regions)
  ;
quit;
```

Then pass that to PROC SUMMARY/MEANS.

```
proc summary data=have classdata=classdata nway;
  class Region1 ServiceID ;
  var total;
  output out=want sum= ;
run;
```

Results:

```
                  Service
Obs    Region1       ID      _TYPE_    _FREQ_    Total

 1        1          1          3         1        50
 2        1          2          3         1        60
 3        1          3          3         0         .
 4        1          4          3         0         .
 5        2          1          3         1        70
 6        2          2          3         0         .
 7        2          3          3         0         .
 8        2          4          3         0         .
```

Comment: if Region1 is non-numeric(character variable) do I need to assign a number to them?  @Tom

Comment: No.  Just use a different method to make the CLASSDATA dataset.  I just used a simple DO loop because your example values were integers.

Comment: How do I make sure to include missing in the classdataset. One more thing when I run my code I get this error. Class variable Region2 was not found in the preload data set or was incompatible with the
       primary data set variable of the same name.
@Tom

Comment: You need have all of the class variables.  Let me update to show how to convert from multiple single variable tables into one multiple variable class dataset.  If you want to include missing in CLASSDATA then do the same way as any other value. But make sure to using MISSING option in PROC SUMMARY so missing values in your real data are included.  Or are you asking to remove the NWAY option and include summaries that don't consider all of the class variables?

Comment: How do I get pass this error Class variable Region1 was not found in the preload data set or was incompatible with the
       primary data set variable of the same name  @Tom

Comment: Your CLASSDATA variables must match the variables in your CLASS statement. The definition (type/length) must match the definition in your actual dataset. Easiest way to make them match is to define the variables in CLASSDATA from the variables in DATA. So either via the SQL code example in my answer. Or for the datastep version something like: `data classdata; if 0 then set have(keep=region1 serviceid); do region1='Atlantic','West'; do ....`

Comment: For example if in the do loop I don't want number 3 how to how exclude it from the list   @Tom

Comment: You can use commas in DO loop.  `do i=1,2,4 to 10;`

Answer (score 1):

The `SUMMARY` Procedure documentation will reveal the option `MISSING`

> **Control the classification levels**
>   …
>     MISSING
>         uses missing values as valid values to create combinations of class variables

```
proc summary data=… missing ;
run;
```

You can also specify one or more variables to use missing as a classification level with the same option on the `CLASS` Statement.

```
  CLASS ServiceID / MISSING;
```

Comment: Did you take a look at what I am really asking? Your response did not apply to my question and did not work. But thanks for trying @Richard